# A box consists of X components, Y of which are defective.

Tags: statistics

**Question**

A box consists of 11 components, 7 of which are defective.

(a)     Components are selected and tested one at a time, without replacement, until a non-defective component is found. Let X be the number of tests required. Find P(X = 4).

(b)     Components are selected and tested, one at a time without replacement, until two consecutive non defective components are obtained. Let X be the number of tests required. Find P(X = 5).

**Answer**

Seems to be a simple application of hypergeometric distribution!
(let d = defective, n = normal)

For part a), if we have the following:

$ 4 $ normal components, $ 7 $ defective components. The probability of getting a normal component on the 4th test is: (i.e. {dddn})

$ P(X=4)=\frac{{7 \choose 3}{4 \choose 1}}{{11 \choose 4}} $

Part b) is similar, except we're aiming to get 2 defective components consecutively. This means {nnndd}

$ 4 $ normal components, $ 7 $ defective components. The probability of getting a normal component on the 4th test is:

$ P(X=5)=\frac{{7 \choose 3}{4 \choose 2}}{{11 \choose 5}} $

These answers aren't correct though, where is the flaw?

I've tried attempting this from the permutations perspective as well (i.e. $ 7 $ `d`'s and and $ 4 $ `n`'s, find P({dddn}) for part a and P({dddnn}) for part b.)

Did something similar for part b), to no avail.

Comment: Please edit your question to include where the answers you want an explanation for came from, what you have tried, and where you might be getting stuck. It helps us help you!

Comment: I attempted to clarify my reasoning behind the answer.